# How to autoload extra module classess automatically like of default namespace "Application_"?

Tags: zend-framework

All the classes under a default namespace `Application_` is autoloaded by default. When you are creating more modules, the classes under that module is not autoloaded.

I tried setting the extra module's namespace on the `application.ini` like

> autoloaderNamespaces[] = "EXTRA_"

but since the folder structure of the extra modules lies inside the `Application` it cannot find it.

How to set this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Bootstrap` class for each module, create a new [module resource autloloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html#zend.loader.autoloader-resource.module):

```
protected function _initResourceAutoloader()
{
    $resourceAutoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => 'Mymodule',
        'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
    ));
}
```

Then, you can use the "standard" folder structure for module-specific classes. For example, a form named `Mymodule_Form_Edit` would reside in the file `modules/mymodule/forms/Edit.php`

**UPDATE**

As noted by @Xerkus and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922837/zendframework-where-to-place-additional-classes-in-modular-directory-structure/6928382#6928382), a module Bootstrap extending `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` will automatically register some standard namespace/path mappings, so no need to manually instantiate a `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader`.

Comment: Well, there was a typo in my answer (now fixed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [application resource modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.modules)

Module bootstrap(if subclass of Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap) register autoloader on instantiation.
Following is array of resources registered with autoloader by default:

```
array(
    'dbtable' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Model_DbTable',
        'path'      => 'models/DbTable',
    ),
    'mappers' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Model_Mapper',
        'path'      => 'models/mappers',
    ),
    'form'    => array(
        'namespace' => 'Form',
        'path'      => 'forms',
    ),
    'model'   => array(
        'namespace' => 'Model',
        'path'      => 'models',
    ),
    'plugin'  => array(
        'namespace' => 'Plugin',
        'path'      => 'plugins',
    ),
    'service' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Service',
        'path'      => 'services',
    ),
    'viewhelper' => array(
        'namespace' => 'View_Helper',
        'path'      => 'views/helpers',
    ),
    'viewfilter' => array(
        'namespace' => 'View_Filter',
        'path'      => 'views/filters',
    ),
)
```

You can add your own module resource type to autoloader from module bootstrap:

```
//module bootstrap for module foo
class Foo_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    function _initMyRes()
    {
        $autoloader = $this->getResourceLoader();
        $autoloader->addResourceType('myres', 'myres/custom/path', 'My_Res');
    }
}
```

first parameter is a key for resource type, second is a path relative to module name, third is a resource prefix.
For example class `Foo_My_Res_Bar` will be autoloaded from `modules/foo/myres/custom/path/Bar.php`

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces is for your own library classes (like the Zend_) classes. Modules are different thing and don't have namespace in that sense.

In the application.ini configuration you will have something like this

```
autoloaderNamespaces.My = "My_"
// these are you library classes

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_LIBRARY "/modules"
// this is your module directory
```

**UPDATE** If you need support for more than one module directory you need ZF 1.11.1 or this [bugfix](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9258)