# ZendFramework - Where to place additional classes in modular directory structure?

Tags: zend-framework, structure

I'm currently working on some kind of web application based on ZendFramework.
In one of the modules there's a need of calculating item price. 
When buying, by providing some promotional code client can get access to one or more discounts.

I thought of making it as decorators (pattern).

Base class calculating price (method "getPrice") can be modified by one of more decorator classes. Each of them can substract some value. 
So, each promotion has its own class implementing some interface (e.g. with method "getPrice")

Of course example is simplified ;)

My question is, where to place this bunch of classes (and interface) in directories structure *

*I'm using default ZF's modular directory structure.

They have something in common with models, maybe helpers? But definitely nothing in common with views...

Another thing is, that they should be bound with module, so they should be placed in that module folder.

Any help, any ideas will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want these to go into `application/modules/somemodule/models` so a class like `Somemodule_Model_SomePromotion` would reside in `application/modules/somemodule/models/SomePromotion.php`.

I believe that the default resource autoloader for a modular setup will be configured to load models with classnames of hat format from that `models` folder. But if not, then add the following into the module (not the app) Bootstrap:

```
protected function _initResourceLoader()
{
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
       'namespace' => 'Somemodule_',
       'basePath'  => dirname(__FILE__),
       'resourceTypes' => array(
            'models' => array(
                'namespace' => 'Model_',
                'path'      => 'models',
            ),
       ),
    ));
}
```

**Update**

Per Comment by @brady.vitrano: If the module bootstrap extends `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap`, then a resource autoloader containing this mapping comes for free. No need to include it manually, unless you wish to add other resource types.

Comment: Friendly Note: Extending `Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap` in a module Bootstrap.php file does not require use of `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` it does it on construct and loads all the standard resource types automatically. If you add `appNamespace = ''` to your application.ini, there is no need to use `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` in your application Bootstrap file. Basically, you don't need call `Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader` manually anymore.

Comment: @brady.vitrano: Thanks for the heads up. I thought so, but wasn't sure. I'll edit the answer to include your info.

Comment: Thanks, but problem is not technical, so there's no need for even a single line of php code ;)

This is only design problem...

I don't think that that kind of feature should be represented as a model. It is rather another layer or maybe model-helper?

Placing them (classes) along with common module models is bad idea imho...

I thought of making another subfolder in my module models directory. 

Again:

Where do you, in your applications, place this kind of feature-classes, that are not ctrl/model/view and definitly should not be placed in main "library" folder as they are module-specific...

Comment: Aaah, I see. From the title and text of the original post, I thought the question was primarily _file location_ rather than class design. I might put this stuff in models, though perhaps in a subfolder `application/models/promotions`, with additional resource type mappings for autoloading. Alternatively, I have seen people create an application-specific library called `App` placed in `library/App`.

Comment: I've created subfolder in module model directory (with type mapping in autoloader) as you propose, and this is quite elegant and natural solution. Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

You should structure your own library like this:

```
/application
    /modules
        // Module structure
/library
    /Package
        /Subpackage
            /ClassName.php
    /Zend
        // Zend Framework Files
```

Where your class name is `Package_Subpackage_ClassName`. You should also add your `Package_` prefix to the autoloader.

Comment: Thanks @adlawson

This is simplest solution, but I think, that in main library dir, should only be application-wide libraries, that extends ZF or provides additional features.

One, that I'm asking of, is rather module-specific one...